# What is an efficent method for in-order processing of events using CCR?

Tags: c#, iterator, ccr

I was experimenting with CCR iterators as a solution to a task that requires parallel processing of tons of data feeds, where the data from each feed needs to be processed in order.  None of the feeds are dependent on each other, so the in-order processing can be paralleled per-feed.

Below is a quick and dirty mockup with one integer feed, which simply shoves integers into a Port at a rate of about 1.5K/second, and then pulls them out using a CCR iterator to keep the in-order processing guarantee.

```
class Program
{
    static Dispatcher dispatcher = new Dispatcher();
    static DispatcherQueue dispatcherQueue = 
       new DispatcherQueue("DefaultDispatcherQueue", dispatcher);
    static Port<int> intPort = new Port<int>();

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Arbiter.Activate(
            dispatcherQueue,
            Arbiter.FromIteratorHandler(new IteratorHandler(ProcessInts)));

        int counter = 0;
        Timer t = new Timer( (x) => 
            { for(int i = 0; i < 1500; ++i) intPort.Post(counter++);}
              , null, 0, 1000);

        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public static IEnumerator<ITask> ProcessInts()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return intPort.Receive();
            int currentValue;
            if( (currentValue = intPort) % 1000 == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}, Current Items In Queue:{1}", 
                  currentValue, intPort.ItemCount);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

What surprised me about this greatly was that CCR could not keep up on a Corei7 box, with the queue size growing without bounds.  In another test to measure the latency from the Post() to the Receive() under a load or ~100 Post/sec., the latency between the first Post() and Receive() in each batch was around 1ms.

Is there something wrong with my mockup?  If so, what is a better way of doing this using CCR?

Comment: Can you elaborate on what CCR is?

Comment: CCR is the Communication and Coordination Runtime, a library designed for asynchronous workflows.  It is part of the Microsoft Robotics Studio, and is now available for free.  Considering it was originally $700 which limited the potential audience, and the mindshare push of TPL, it's been regulated to the shadows except in certain industries.  It's not dead though, CCR Workflows are part of the new asynch framework, and the CCR Devs said there would be a big announcement "as soon as next month" in January.  Check the CCR tag for more info.

Comment: Where is the reference to the "big announcement"?

Comment: I guess it's just an announcement, not necessarily a big one.  [link to thread on CCR forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/roboticsccr/thread/fb6c4f4b-ab1d-49b4-8b78-0307d4da43bf).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I agree, this does indeed seem weird. Your code seems initially to perform smoothly, but after a few thousand items, processor usage rises to the point where performance is really lacklustre. This disturbs me and suggests a problem in the framework. After a play with your code, I can't really identify why this is the case. I'd suggest taking this problem to the [Microsoft Robotics Forums](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/roboticsccr/threads) and seeing if you can get George Chrysanthakopoulos (or one of the other CCR brains) to tell you what the problem is. I can however surmise that your code as it stands is terribly inefficient.

The way that you are dealing with "popping" items from the Port is very inefficient. Essentially the iterator is woken each time there is a message in the Port and it deals with only one message (despite the fact that there might be several hundred more in the Port), then hangs on the `yield` while control is passed back to the framework. At the point that the yielded receiver causes another "awakening" of the iterator, many many messages have filled the Port. Pulling a thread from the Dispatcher to deal with only a single item (when many have piled up in the meantime) is almost certainly not the best way to get good throughput.

I've modded your code such that after the yield, we check the Port to see if there are any further messages queued and deal with them too, thereby completely emptying the Port before we yield back to the framework. I've also refactored your code somewhat to use `CcrServiceBase` which simplifies the syntax of some of the tasks you are doing:

```
internal class Test:CcrServiceBase
{
    private readonly Port<int> intPort = new Port<int>();
    private Timer timer;
    public Test() : base(new DispatcherQueue("DefaultDispatcherQueue",
                                             new Dispatcher(0,
                                                            "dispatcher")))
    {

    }

    public void StartTest() {
        SpawnIterator(ProcessInts);
        var counter = 0;
        timer = new Timer(x =>
                          {
                              for (var i = 0; i < 1500; ++i)
                                  intPort.Post(counter++);
                          }
                          ,
                          null,
                          0,
                          1000);
    }

    public IEnumerator<ITask> ProcessInts()
    {
        while (true)
        {
            yield return intPort.Receive();
            int currentValue = intPort;
            ReportCurrent(currentValue);
            while(intPort.Test(out currentValue))
            {
                ReportCurrent(currentValue);
            }
        }
    }

    private void ReportCurrent(int currentValue)
    {
        if (currentValue % 1000 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, Current Items In Queue:{1}",
                              currentValue,
                              intPort.ItemCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could do away with the iterator completely, as it's not really well used in your example (although I'm not entirely sure what effect this has on the order of processing):

```
internal class Test : CcrServiceBase
{
    private readonly Port<int> intPort = new Port<int>();
    private Timer timer;

    public Test() : base(new DispatcherQueue("DefaultDispatcherQueue",
                                             new Dispatcher(0,
                                                            "dispatcher")))
    {

    }

    public void StartTest()
    {
        Activate(
            Arbiter.Receive(true,
                            intPort,
                            i =>
                            {
                                ReportCurrent(i);
                                int currentValue;
                                while (intPort.Test(out currentValue))
                                {
                                    ReportCurrent(currentValue);
                                }
                            }));
        var counter = 0;
        timer = new Timer(x =>
                          {
                              for (var i = 0; i < 500000; ++i)
                              {
                                  intPort.Post(counter++);
                              }
                          }
                          ,
                          null,
                          0,
                          1000);
    }



    private void ReportCurrent(int currentValue)
    {
        if (currentValue % 1000000 == 0)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0}, Current Items In Queue:{1}",
                              currentValue,
                              intPort.ItemCount);
        }
    }
}
```

Both these examples significantly increase throughput by orders of magnitude. Hope this helps.

Comment: Finally had time to experiment some more this weekend, and those solutions definitely are a huge improvement.  I am really interested about the performance falloff of the original solution though, since not understanding why it occurred means I might run into it again, but it looks like the official CCR forum is a better place for that discussion.